# Is the following proof that if $T: V \rightarrow V$ as eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $aT$ has eigenvalue $a\lambda$ correct

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I found this proof here:https://math.berkeley.edu/~lpachter/110_99/soln7.pdf (first question of part 2).

For convenience, the statement and proof are listed below.

Statement: If $T:V\rightarrow V$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$, $aT$ has eigenvalue $a\lambda$.

Proof: Let $x$ be an eigenvector for the eigenvalue λ. (aT)(x) = a(T(x)) = a(λx) = λ(ax), so $ax$ is an eigenvector of $aT$ with eigenvalue λ.

How does this prove that $aT$ has eigenvalue of $a\lambda$?

Answer (score 2):

It's not that $ax$ is an eigenvector $aT$, $x$ still remains an eigenvector.  Instead you have that if $Tx = \lambda x$ then $aTx = a\lambda x$ or rather $(aT - a\lambda I)x = 0$.  Surely $ax$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, but it depends on where you associate the constant $a$.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $a\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, we want to prove that there exists a vector $v$ such that $aTv = a\lambda v$. The proof shows that $x$, the eigenvector of $T$ associated with $\lambda$, is an example of such a $v$, which means that such a $v$ exists.